# How do I use multiple values of all matches returned by regular expression in jmeter in a single HTTP request

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm capturing multiple values with a regular expression, and that expression returns 20 matches as shown in image [RegExMatches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsjQi.png),
My regular expression is something like this [RegEx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRJ6S.png).
How do I use multiple values in post data of my HTTP request which is something like [PostData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c01dm.png)

I tried with MatchNR and -1 and call with ${candidateGUID_gN} N being the match number but this didn't workout.
How do I use the Extracted values in Post data ? or will I have to make different Regular Expressions for each value ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way of achieving this is building your request using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://groovy-lang.org/), take a look at the following [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands:

1. [Arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/Arguments.html)
2. `vars` aka [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)
3. `sampler` aka [HTTPSamplerBase](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html)

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

And please [stop posting code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) it's not very polite / disrespect to the community.